# Lotus Notes Database template inheritance not replicating

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a Lotus Notes database with 5 replicas.

I changed the template name inheritance from "XYZv1" to "XYZv2".

I expected that overnight, the template name inheritance will update to "XYZv2" after servers replication but it did not.

What could be missing/wrong in my db ACL?

1. Replica: Template name is XYZv2.ntf
2. Replica: Template name is XYZv1.ntf
3. Replica: Template name is XYZv1.ntf
4. Replica: Template name is XYZv1.ntf
5. Replica: Template name is XYZv1.ntf

Answer (score 1):

It will not replicate template info if in Replication options "Send" tab option "Send changes in application title and catalog info to other replicas" is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

The servers must have at least Designer access to each other.  This is usually done by adding a group containing all the servers (e.g., LocalDomainServers) to the ACL. Check the ACL to see if such a group is there, and check the members of the group in the Domino Directory.